# How to find the last opened file descriptor?

Tags: c

Consider I have a process called `a.out` , In that process, i have opened the 10 files using a `open()` function.

Consider that time I get the last descriptor is 13. So I need to know is there is any way to find the last opened descriptor in the process.

For that I am using a `getrlimit` like this

```
   if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,&r1)<0)
              perror("error");
```

But when I am priting this I get 4096 in my system. SO Is there is any way to do this?

Comment: What is meant by "Consider that time I get the last descriptor is 13"?

Comment: @RubixRechvin - After opening a 10 files, the last opened file got the file descriptor as 13.

Comment: 4096 means the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process + 1.

Comment: @iharob - so how to i know the last opened files descriptor??

Comment: Keep track of the information if you need it.

Comment: I hate it when devs try to come up with cute solutions like this instead just properly tracking their file descriptors. The most straightforward solution is almost always the best.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the highest allocated file descriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899038/getting-the-highest-allocated-file-descriptor)

Comment: What specifically do you want to know? The number of the most recently opened file? Or the largest descriptor number? What about files opened by library functions that your program calls? What do you need the value for?

Comment: You may want to try reading /proc/<pid>/fd directory in your code to see how many fds were opened. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @vtha this would work in a sense, but seems an unnecessarily complicated hack considering the simplicity of the task. Remembering an fd is as simple as storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (sensible) magic way to do this. You must remember it in a variable somewhere. Each time you open a file, update this variable.

(`getrlimit` with `RLIMIT_NOFILE` tells you how many files you *can* open, not how many you *have* opened).